# How to add text in the axis in matplotlib figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid, label

[image]

I want to add text in the axis in the figure like above figure.

I have worked out the figure below but can not add text in the axis"20℃"  Thank you.

[image]

below are my code:

```
theltaa=array([20,800,1200])
thermalconductivity=array([53.3,27.3,27.3])
fig = figure(figsize=(8,4))
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7])
ylim(20,60)
fig.patch.set_alpha(0.0)
ax.patch.set_alpha(0.0)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(200))
#ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%d'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(100))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(20))
#ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%d'))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(10))


ax.axvline(20, linestyle='--', color='k') 
text(25,0,"$20^{\circ}C$', fontsize=12)### this does not work

ax.xaxis.grid(True,'minor')
ax.yaxis.grid(True,'minor')
ax.xaxis.grid(True,'major',linewidth=2)
ax.yaxis.grid(True,'major',linewidth=2)
plot(theltaa,thermalconductivity,'H-')
xlabel(r"$\theta_a(^{\circ}C)$",fontsize=18)
ylabel(r"$\lambda_a(W/mK)$",fontsize=18)
show()
fig.savefig('tc.png', transparent=True)
```

I tried to add

```
text(25,0,"$20^{\circ}C$', fontsize=12)### this does not work
```

somehow, this does not work...

Comment: TL;DR; `ax.axvline(x)` and `ax.axhline(y)`

Comment: Thank you. It works good, however, when I use "ax.axvline(20, linestyle='--', color='k') 
ax.text(25,0,"$20^{\circ}C$",rotation='90')" code to let the reference line label 20℃"appear, there is no response.

Comment: I am no longer sure that this is a duplicate.

Comment: Dear tcaswell, kindly remove my question from duplicate, please. Thank you.